# Google Analytics V2 SDK for Android EasyTracker giving errors

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have followed the tutorial for the new Google Analytics V2 SDK for Android located here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

Unfortunately whenever I go to run the application the reporting is not working and this is the messages that logcat gives me:

```
07-09 09:13:16.978: W/Ads(13933): No Google Analytics: Library Incompatible.
07-09 09:13:16.994: I/Ads(13933): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("2BB916E1BD6BE6407582A429D763EC71");
07-09 09:13:17.018: I/Ads(13933): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":0,"session_id":"7925570029955749351","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a14fd91432961bd","u_w":360,"msid":"com.mysampleapp.sampleapp","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.0.1","mv":"8013013.com.android.vending","isu":"2BB916E1BD6BE6407582A429D763EC71","cipa":1,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.mysampleapp.sampleapp","hl":"en","u_h":592,"carrier":"311480","ptime":0,"u_audio":3});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-09 09:13:17.041: W/ActivityManager(220): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }: not found
07-09 09:13:17.049: W/GAV2(13933): Thread[main,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
07-09 09:13:17.057: W/GAV2(13933): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initializea() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
07-09 09:13:17.088: D/libEGL(13933): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-09 09:13:17.096: D/libEGL(13933): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
07-09 09:13:17.096: D/libEGL(13933): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
07-09 09:13:17.096: D/libEGL(13933): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
```

Here is my code (I have redacted some of the code that had to do with httppost, etc.):

```
    package com.mysampleapp.sampleapp;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class viewRandom extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.viewrandom);



            uservote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new randomViewClass().execute();

        }

        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
        }

        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
        }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't know how to change "en_dash" to regular dash.

Comment: I am getting this same error for no reason I can see, but the SDK is working correctly.

Comment: Just delete the en dash character and replace it with a dash character

Comment: I tried this but not working. Same error: W/GAV2(13933): Thread[main,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
W/GAV2(13933): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initializea() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found out what the problem was with this.  It was within my analytics.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-0000000-00</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">20</string>
</resources>
```

What had happened was when I pasted my trackingId into the file, eclipse had converted it to an "en dash" automatically and Google was unable to read my trackingId properly.  Changing the en dashes to regular dashes worked fine and now everything in functioning.

Comment: What's the meaning of "regular" here, is 'en dashes' the ASCII and 'regular dashes' the UTF format?

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is an old post, but I wanted to provide some more information sense this is exactly the same error I was receiving today.

Prince is exactly correct, it's from the dashes. For most deleting the dash and typing out - again will work. 
But once you clean your project again it will switch it back to the en_dash which might be mysho's problem.

It does this automatically because of Android Lint. You can disable it though!

> Go into your preferences (I'm on a mac so for me it's Eclipse ->
>   Preferences)
>
> Go to Android Go to Lint error Checking
>
> You can either disable Lint checker completely or do what I did,
>   disable just the en_dash thing
>
> Either fine the one called "TypographyDashes" under
>   Usability:Typography or search "dash" inside the search box. Either
>   way it should come up with TypographyDashes.
>
> Highlight it and turn it to "Ignore" under the severity
>
> From there Click apply and then allow it to relint

Hope I could help

Comment: after searching for over 5 hours on how to fix this problem with the dashes no one put it more elegantly than you Travis. I wish I could give you +10 upvotes!

Comment: once you clean your project again it will switch it back to the en_dash <-- this was my problem as I was changing it then doing a clean, which would just revert it back. hope that helps others too

Answer (score 4):

It's better to add an attribute into the "resources" tag like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
  <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-12345678-X</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```